integral of exponential of Fourier series
I have encountered the following integral:
\begin{equation}
\int_0^{1} e^{-i F(x)} dx, \quad F(x) = \sum_{k=1}^L a_k \sin(2\pi k x) + b_k \cos(2\pi k x).
\end{equation} I have found several great sources such that this one, which provided a satisfactory closed-form solution for the integral when $L = 1$.
I have spent a considerable amount of time trying to generalize the approach in that post to the case for arbitrary natural numbers $L > 1$, but have not succeeded so far. I would appreciate it if anyone could give me advice/guidance. Are there closed-form (or compact) solutions for the integral when $L = 2, 3, \ldots$?

I would say it’s unlikely for there to be a closed form for generic $F$. What applications would a closed form help you with, if any?
